# Find image size with asp (vbscript) for crop script.

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I writ a basic cropping script. In VBscript. As follows:

```
<%Set Jpeg = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Jpeg")
getsec = DateDiff("s","01/01/04",now())
filename = "screenshots/"&getsec&".png"
imgfile = request("imgfile")
Jpeg.Open Server.MapPath(imgfile)
Jpeg.Crop 0, 38, 320, 460
Jpeg.Canvas.DrawPNG 0, 0,  Server.MapPath("watermark.png")
Jpeg.PNGOutput = True
Jpeg.Save Server.MapPath(filename)
%>
<%=filename%>
```

However instead of hard coding these variables:

```
Jpeg.Crop 0, 38, 320, 460
```

I would like someway of using vbscript to find out the image size before I crop it, so that if different image sizes are uploaded the script can be more flexible. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: this helped me achieve what i wanted, if you put it in an answer I will accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Jpeg` object (ASPJpeg instance) has `.OriginalWidth` and `.OriginalHeight` properties which are accessible after invoking `.Open` method. You can use them.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the loadpicture function. (see also http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_loadpicture.asp)

To get the pixels, you could use this:

```
Dim sPath
sPath = "C:\myPicture.jpg"
dim iWidth, iHeight
dim oFs, oImg
Set oFs= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oImg = loadpicture(sPath)
iWidth = round(oImg.width / 26.4583)
iHeight = round(oImg.height / 26.4583)
Set oImg = Nothing
```

Comment: Not relevant to this question - what you found is **client side VBScript** while classic ASP means server side VBScript.

Comment: OK, thanks for catching that.. seems this is not available in the classic asp server-side objects

Comment: Doesn't work on 64-bit server, or load PNG files properly. LoadPicture works fine server side, not neccesarily *client side VBScript* ...